# add_meta_box: Datepicker like the one for postdate?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, custom-field, metabox

I've built a custom post type called "Events". Each event has a future date and I don't want to use the normal `postdate` of the post.

I want to use `add_meta_box` to add some inputs for this "event-date".

Do you have any idea how I could use the probably same date-picker as there is right now for the `postdate` in a meta_box?

Thank you in advance.

matt

update:

```
add_action("admin_init", "admin_init");

function admin_init(){
    add_meta_box("event-date-meta", "Event Date", "event_date", "wr_event", "side", "low");
}


function year_completed(){
    global $post;
    $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
    //…
    ?>
    <label>Event-Date:</label>
    <div id="timestampdiv" class=""><?php touch_time(($action == 'edit'),1,4); ?></div>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: take a look at my answer to your other question http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/48408/2487

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never really thought about it, but it should indeed be a good option.

The date picker is called from wp-admin/includes/meta-boxes.php (line 183) as:

```
<div id="timestampdiv" class="hide-if-js"><?php touch_time(($action == 'edit'),1,4); ?></div>
```

and touch_time() is defined in wp-admin/includes/template.php (line 550) as:

```
/**
 * {@internal Missing Short Description}}
 *
 * @since 0.71
 *
 * @param unknown_type $edit
 * @param unknown_type $for_post
 * @param unknown_type $tab_index
 * @param unknown_type $multi
 */
function touch_time( $edit = 1, $for_post = 1, $tab_index = 0, $multi = 0 ) {
    global $wp_locale, $post, $comment;

    if ( $for_post )
        $edit = ! ( in_array($post->post_status, array('draft', 'pending') ) && (!$post->post_date_gmt || '0000-00-00 00:00:00' == $post->post_date_gmt ) );

    $tab_index_attribute = '';
    if ( (int) $tab_index > 0 )
        $tab_index_attribute = " tabindex=\"$tab_index\"";

    // echo '<label for="timestamp" style="display: block;"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="edit_date" value="1" id="timestamp"'.$tab_index_attribute.' /> '.__( 'Edit timestamp' ).'</label><br />';

    $time_adj = current_time('timestamp');
    $post_date = ($for_post) ? $post->post_date : $comment->comment_date;
    $jj = ($edit) ? mysql2date( 'd', $post_date, false ) : gmdate( 'd', $time_adj );
    $mm = ($edit) ? mysql2date( 'm', $post_date, false ) : gmdate( 'm', $time_adj );
    $aa = ($edit) ? mysql2date( 'Y', $post_date, false ) : gmdate( 'Y', $time_adj );
    $hh = ($edit) ? mysql2date( 'H', $post_date, false ) : gmdate( 'H', $time_adj );
    $mn = ($edit) ? mysql2date( 'i', $post_date, false ) : gmdate( 'i', $time_adj );
    $ss = ($edit) ? mysql2date( 's', $post_date, false ) : gmdate( 's', $time_adj );

    $cur_jj = gmdate( 'd', $time_adj );
    $cur_mm = gmdate( 'm', $time_adj );
    $cur_aa = gmdate( 'Y', $time_adj );
    $cur_hh = gmdate( 'H', $time_adj );
    $cur_mn = gmdate( 'i', $time_adj );

    $month = "<select " . ( $multi ? '' : 'id="mm" ' ) . "name=\"mm\"$tab_index_attribute>\n";
    for ( $i = 1; $i < 13; $i = $i +1 ) {
        $monthnum = zeroise($i, 2);
        $month .= "\t\t\t" . '<option value="' . $monthnum . '"';
        if ( $i == $mm )
            $month .= ' selected="selected"';
        $month .= '>' . $monthnum . '-' . $wp_locale->get_month_abbrev( $wp_locale->get_month( $i ) ) . "</option>\n";
    }
    $month .= '</select>';

    $day = '<input type="text" ' . ( $multi ? '' : 'id="jj" ' ) . 'name="jj" value="' . $jj . '" size="2" maxlength="2"' . $tab_index_attribute . ' autocomplete="off" />';
    $year = '<input type="text" ' . ( $multi ? '' : 'id="aa" ' ) . 'name="aa" value="' . $aa . '" size="4" maxlength="4"' . $tab_index_attribute . ' autocomplete="off" />';
    $hour = '<input type="text" ' . ( $multi ? '' : 'id="hh" ' ) . 'name="hh" value="' . $hh . '" size="2" maxlength="2"' . $tab_index_attribute . ' autocomplete="off" />';
    $minute = '<input type="text" ' . ( $multi ? '' : 'id="mn" ' ) . 'name="mn" value="' . $mn . '" size="2" maxlength="2"' . $tab_index_attribute . ' autocomplete="off" />';

    echo '<div class="timestamp-wrap">';
    /* translators: 1: month input, 2: day input, 3: year input, 4: hour input, 5: minute input */
    printf(__('%1$s%2$s, %3$s @ %4$s : %5$s'), $month, $day, $year, $hour, $minute);

    echo '</div><input type="hidden" id="ss" name="ss" value="' . $ss . '" />';

    if ( $multi ) return;

    echo "\n\n";
    foreach ( array('mm', 'jj', 'aa', 'hh', 'mn') as $timeunit ) {
        echo '<input type="hidden" id="hidden_' . $timeunit . '" name="hidden_' . $timeunit . '" value="' . $$timeunit . '" />' . "\n";
        $cur_timeunit = 'cur_' . $timeunit;
        echo '<input type="hidden" id="'. $cur_timeunit . '" name="'. $cur_timeunit . '" value="' . $$cur_timeunit . '" />' . "\n";
    }
?>

<p>
<a href="#edit_timestamp" class="save-timestamp hide-if-no-js button"><?php _e('OK'); ?></a>
<a href="#edit_timestamp" class="cancel-timestamp hide-if-no-js"><?php _e('Cancel'); ?></a>
</p>
<?php
}
```

Doesn't look very difficult to work it from there... will try.

Comment: Thank you! Let me know what you come up with! If you remove the "hide-if-js" class it already appears as I want it! I updated my question with some code …

Comment: I just don't know how to store/save this information correctly! And how I read it afterwards. I of course want to sort all my events by simply by date!

Comment: I would store it as you'd normally store a custom-value, using `update_post_meta` so you'd probably split that touch_time() function in two, using one of them to build the form as your callback in add_meta_box and the other one fetching values from $_POST[] abd saving, hooked to the `save_post` action.

Comment: Thank you! Would you mind giving me an example of how I could store those values and read them in the front-end? I've never worked with this stuff before. I would really appreciate it! What do you mean by splitting the `touch_time()` function in two?