# meta_box or custom_field as a second tinymce post-instance?

Tags: posts, custom-taxonomy, custom-field, metabox

probably a rather weird question but I have no idea if this is possible or not!?

I created a `custom-post-type` to handle events. An event always has a future date but once this date is over I want to be able to write a review of the event and add this to the post itself.

So imagine an event as a kind of group of two posts. The first post is the one when it get's published. With a description of the event, a date of the event, etc.

Once the event is over I somehow would like to write a "recap" of the event - how it was, some photos, etc.

Do you generally have any idea how I could solve this? So that the same event-post suddenly has a kind of "subpost" with a review in it?

I was wondering if I could solve this via a `custom-field` that adds a completely new instance of the TinyMCE editor underneath the already existing one. So that I could write two posts inside of one post? Sounds silly I know. But then I would have one event-link that (if the date of the event is over) would have a somehow differently formatted second post-item with the review of the event in it!

Any ideas on that? How could I solve such a thing? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this answers both of your questions(this and [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/48398/add-meta-box-datepicker-like-the-one-for-postdate)), Take a look at [My Meta box class](http://en.bainternet.info/2012/how-i-add-a-wordpress-metabox) which lets add nay type of field you want in a custom metabox.

Once you have the class all you need to do is something like this:

```
//include the main class file
require_once("meta-box-class/my-meta-box-class.php");
// configure your meta box
$config = array(
    'id' => 'event_review_box',             // meta box id, unique per meta box
    'title' => 'Event Review',          // meta box title
    'pages' => array('event'),          // post types, assuming that your post type name is event
    'context' => 'normal',              // where the meta box appear: normal (default), advanced, side; optional
    'priority' => 'high',               // order of meta box: high (default), low; optional
    'fields' => array(),                // list of meta fields (can be added by field arrays) or using the class's functions
    'local_images' => false,            // Use local or hosted images (meta box images for add/remove)
    'use_with_theme' => false           //change path if used with theme set to true, false for a plugin or anything else for a custom path(default false).
);
// Initiate your meta box
$my_meta2 = new AT_Meta_Box($config);
//Add fields to your meta box
$my_meta2->addWysiwyg('wysiwyg_field_id',array('name'=> 'Event Recap'));
//Finish Meta Box Deceleration
$my_meta2->Finish();
```

then to add a new metabox for the event date field

```
// configure your meta box
$config = array(
    'id' => 'event_date_box',           // meta box id, unique per meta box
    'title' => 'Event date',            // meta box title
    'pages' => array('event'),          // post types, assuming that your post type name is event
    'context' => 'normal',              // where the meta box appear: normal (default), advanced, side; optional
    'priority' => 'high',               // order of meta box: high (default), low; optional
    'fields' => array(),                // list of meta fields (can be added by field arrays) or using the class's functions
    'local_images' => false,            // Use local or hosted images (meta box images for add/remove)
    'use_with_theme' => false           //change path if used with theme set to true, false for a plugin or anything else for a custom path(default false).
);
// Initiate your meta box
$my_meta = new AT_Meta_Box($config);
//Add fields to your meta box
$my_meta->addDate('date_field_id',array('name'=> 'Event Date '));
//Finish Meta Box Deceleration
$my_meta->Finish();
```

and you get something that looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Just wow! Thank you! This helps a lot! Would be really cool though to have the same date-picker as for the `postdate`. Maybe you think about it for future releases of your class. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is it possible to use German date format with your date and time pickers?

Comment: The class can handle any of the format types listed here http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/$.datepicker.formatDate

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. Two more questions though. My site is about events as you read above - therefore I want to list all events and sort them by their event-date. I use `text_date` right now and changed it to my desired date-format - just perfect. However do you have any idea how I could sort my posts by this event-date in the right order?

Comment: if you want to sort based on the date you should save the date in a unix timestemp format then you should be able to short based on the date.